# Access VM Server using name or static IP

Tags: networking, 18.04, virtualbox, configuration, virtualbox-networking

I'm trying to create a better web development environment by using a VirtualBox VM running Ubuntu 18.04 but I don't know how to configure the network settings to achieve what I want.

I want to be able to access the server from the host using SSH as well as the browser using either a name or an IP-address. I did get this to work by using a Bridged Adapter in the network settings but the IP-address is dynamic so I have to log in to the server and check the IP-address every time in order to access the server through the browser etc.

I want to configure the server so I can browse the websites I create and SSH into it from the host using a name (like a domain name without setting it up as a live server) or using a static IP instead of the current dynamic IP. Basically I just want the ability to use the server without checking the IP every time. I'd prefer the name option so that I don't have to remember the static IP but as long as I can use one of the two I'm happy.

How would I go about doing this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to write it here 2 years ago after I found the solution but I'll do it now in case it helps anyone in the future. The only thing I was missing were to set up port forwarding between the VM and host for the ports needed while using a bridged network adapter. After adding port 80 I was able to browse to the VMs websites using localhost etc